# Elm onInput event handler not working on contenteditable element

Tags: dom-events, contenteditable, elm

I want to update my model everytime someone modifies an editable table cell.

The [onInput](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#onInput) function seems to be working well on `input` elements, but on a `td` element with `contenteditable="true"`, the handler function never gets called.
Why?
How should I detect content change in an editable table cell then?

Please see **lines 74 and 78** in the following piece of code
(I just took the "buttons" example of the Elm guide and added my stuff to it to have something minimal but runnable):

```
module Main exposing (..)

-- Press buttons to increment and decrement a counter.
--
-- Read how it works:
--   https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/buttons.html
--


import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, table, tbody, tr, td, input)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)
import Html.Attributes exposing (contenteditable)



-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL


type alias Model = Int


init : Model
init =
  0



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = Increment
  | Decrement


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      model + 1

    Decrement ->
      model - 1


testOnInputHandler : String -> Msg
testOnInputHandler str =
  let
    log = Debug.log "in testOnInputHandler" "here"
  in
    Increment

-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (String.fromInt model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    , table []
      [ tbody []
        [ tr [] 
          [ td [ contenteditable True, onInput testOnInputHandler] [ text "editable!" ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    , input [ onInput testOnInputHandler ] []
    ]
```

Comment: Please put all relevant information (in this case the code in particular) in the question itself. Consider what will happen if someone else comes across this question looking for help on the same issue, and finds that the external code referenced has either been removed or changed significantly.

Comment: Pasted the code into the question but there is no line numbering which was very useful in the gist.

Comment: I recall that the strucutre of events from contenteditable is different, and onInput won't work. Check mdn and build your own

Comment: @A.Sallai: Thanks. You can still link to the gist, but referring to the actual constructs in the code instead of line numbers and extracting small snippets to illustrate, would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`onInput` will get the string from `target.value` which does not exist for `contenteditable` `input` events.

You may want to grab `innerText` for example instead:

```
onContentEditableInput : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onContentEditableInput tagger =
    Html.Events.stopPropagationOn "input"
        (Json.map (\x -> ( x, True )) (Json.map tagger innerText))

innerText : Json.Decoder String
innerText =
  Json.at ["target", "innerText"] Json.string
```

Comment: What is "tagger" parameter ? How to use this function in view ?